Difference between anova () and summary ()?
Original post summary:

I want to run a two-way repeated measures ANOVA.
What is the difference between the following functions: anova(), Anova(), and summary()?
Why are the p values in my summary()  output different from the p values generated from my post-hoc test?

Summarized Answer: I am actually running a multilevel regression model and using ANOVA functions to test my model. In regard to post-hoc tests, it would be best to use the estimated means via the emmeans package and then perform a Tukey's test. Originally, I was using the Bonferroni method and using raw data.
Thank you for all of the help! I will be looking into multilevel regression models and learning the appropriate code for repeated measures ANOVA.
Below are chunks of my UPDATED code and output if interested.
anova() input:
model2 <- lmer(USV~Condition+Dominance+(1|ID), data=Baseline) 
anova(model2)

anova() output:
Type III Analysis of Variance Table with Satterthwaite's method
          Sum Sq Mean Sq NumDF DenDF F value   Pr(>F)   
Condition 579718  193239     3    33  6.5358 0.001363 **
Dominance  47605   47605     1    10  1.6101 0.233216   
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
    

summary() input():
summary(model2)

summary() output():
Linear mixed model fit by REML. t-tests use Satterthwaite's method ['lmerModLmerTest']
Formula: USV ~ Condition + Dominance + (1 | ID)
   Data: Baseline

REML criterion at convergence: 600.7

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-2.2442 -0.5908  0.0789  0.5528  2.2547 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 ID       (Intercept) 71006    266.5   
 Residual             29566    171.9   
Number of obs: 48, groups:  ID, 12

Fixed effects:
               Estimate Std. Error      df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)      916.65     122.12   12.95   7.506 4.57e-06 ***
ConditionONE    -148.17      70.20   33.00  -2.111   0.0425 *  
ConditionTHREE   152.83      70.20   33.00   2.177   0.0367 *  
ConditionTWO     -61.75      70.20   33.00  -0.880   0.3854    
DominanceSUB    -205.12     161.66   10.00  -1.269   0.2332    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) CndONE CTHREE CndTWO
ConditinONE -0.287                     
CondtnTHREE -0.287  0.500              
ConditinTWO -0.287  0.500  0.500       
DominancSUB -0.662  0.000  0.000  0.000

Post-hoc input:
em<-emmeans(model2, pairwise ~ Condition)
em

Post-hoc output:
$emmeans
 Condition emmean   SE   df lower.CL upper.CL
 Control      814 91.5 16.1      620     1008
 ONE          666 91.5 16.1      472      860
 THREE        967 91.5 16.1      773     1161
 TWO          752 91.5 16.1      558      946

Results are averaged over the levels of: Dominance 
Degrees-of-freedom method: kenward-roger 
Confidence level used: 0.95 

$contrasts
 contrast        estimate   SE df t.ratio p.value
 Control - ONE      148.2 70.2 33   2.111  0.1708
 Control - THREE   -152.8 70.2 33  -2.177  0.1507
 Control - TWO       61.8 70.2 33   0.880  0.8153
 ONE - THREE       -301.0 70.2 33  -4.288  0.0008
 ONE - TWO          -86.4 70.2 33  -1.231  0.6120
 THREE - TWO        214.6 70.2 33   3.057  0.0218

Results are averaged over the levels of: Dominance 
Degrees-of-freedom method: kenward-roger 
P value adjustment: tukey method for comparing a family of 4 estimates 


There's a lot going on here. First, you don't seem to be conducting a repeated-measures anova but a multilevel regression model, which you then test using anova functions.
Second, anova() and Anova(), when applied to one model, give you the overall effect of a factor, meaning they tell you whether there are any differences between any of the groups. summary() gives you the regression output, which gives you the differences between your predictors' reference levels and other levels and not the overall effects.
Third issue is why you get significant p-values in the summary output but not in post hoc tests. summary() does not apply any p-value adjustment, post-hoc tests do, and usually this leads to less significant effects in the post hoc tests than in the summary output.
However, you have chosen to run an entirely separate t-test using raw data instead of running the post-hoc comparisons using estimated means from your model, and you actually get a lower p-value from your post-hoc tests. This is probably due to your t-test comparisons not taking into account the effect of status. It would be better to extract the estimated marginal means for post-hoc comparisons from the model (e.g. using emmeans package) instead of from raw data. Now the comparisons for condition do not adjust for status, which you included into the model and therefore it seems important.
In addition, Bonferroni is often considered overly strict adjustment. You can use for instance Tukey's which is perhaps the typical choice for a model like yours.

EDIT. So, you are running a multilevel model here, which seems like good option. However, you may want to read a bit about multilevel models so you are in better control of what you are doing.
(You could also run a repeated-measures ANOVA, but multilevel models handle missing values better, though you don't seem to have missing values so that's not relevant. However, multilevel models also don't make the sphericity assumption RM-ANOVA does, so they are often preferable, being more robust/flexible that way)
And it seems you are interested in comparing means between different conditions while controlling for status. My suggestion would be to take your model and use emmeans to compare model-based means using tukey's HSD test, like this:
install.packages("emmeans")
library(emmeans)

em<-emmeans(model, pairwise ~ Condition)
em

^this gives you the estimated marginal means for each Condition & comparisons between each condition automatically adjusted with Tukey's procedure. Such comparisons are what is often reported from a model like yours.
Another thing that might be of interest to you that you can do is to compute the intra-class correlation of participant ID, like this:
performance::icc(model)

you can also calculate this by hand, this is just your Random effects'
maleID/(maleID+Residual). The result will tell you how much of the variance in your dependent variable is attributable to between-participant differences.

This is very helpful—thank you.
I will be updating my post with the information you’ve provided to make sure I’m following along correctly.

See my edit, @Butterscotch

Your edit was very helpful - I was able to perform the Tukey's test following the code you've provided (thanks!). If you are interested in the output, I will put it in my post. There was only one significant difference after using estimated means from my model -- but that's okay with me.

I'm glad it helped! If your critical p-value level is the typical p < .05, you can also consider the THREE-TWO comparison significant.
